# Multidimensional array of struct - Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I have a pointer to array of structure and when I try to initialize it, I get a segmentation fault.

```
MyStruct **** node = NULL;
node[0][0][0] = new MyStruct();
```

I tried to use 2D array and it Works fine.

What is wrong?

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer

Comment: Isn't vector slower? Ok, now I rewrited it to `vector <vector <vector <MyStruct* > > > node;` and still segfault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to dynamically allocate the array first, using the `new` operator:

```
MyStruct ****node = new MyStruct***[MAX_SIZE];
for(int i=0; i<MAX_SIZE; ++i) node[i] = new MyStruct**[MAX_SIZE];
for(int i=0; i<MAX_SIZE; ++i) 
  for(int j=0; j<MAX_SIZE; ++j) node[i][j] = new MyStruct*[MAX_SIZE];
node[0][0][0] = new MyStruct();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate memory before using it. You can't just jump 3 levels without allocating and use it.

Allocate `node` first. Then you can access `node[0]`.

Now if you allocate `node[0]`, you can access `node[0][0]`.

Go on like this.

Comment: But in general, prefer using `std::vector`

Comment: @lethal-guitar Yeah sure. Just answering to the question.

Comment: Yeah, that was meant mainly for the OP :)